# Program fails to continue when target word is written twice

Tags: c++, istringstream

My source code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    string target_word=argv[1];     //The word you want to change
    string changed_word=argv[2];     ///The word you want to change it to
    //target_word=target_word+' ';
    string line;     //Used hold each line during processes
    string word;     //Used to hold each word in the line during processes
    size_t position;     //Used to hold the position of the first character in the word

    while(getline(cin, line)){     //Grab each line one at a time
        istringstream iss(line);
        while(iss>>word){     //Grab each word from the line one at a time
            if(word==target_word){     //Check if the current word is the target word
                position=line.find(target_word);     //Find the starting position of the word
                line.replace(position, word.length(), changed_word);     //Change the target word to the word you chose to change it to
            }
        }
        cout<<line<<"\n";     //Output the altered line
    }
    //cout<<target_word<<"END"<<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

I need this program to read a text file and then replace `target_word` with `changed_word`. It seems to work in almost all test cases except when the `target_word` is written twice without a space in between, i.e. if the `target_word` is "input" and `changed_word` is "output" then the program changes "inputinput" to "outputoutput" and then doesn't change any other samples of "input" to "output". How could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
while(iss>>word)
```

will take a whitespace-delimited word and store it in `word`. If the input is "input input", the stream will write "input" into `word` and stop at the space. On the next iteration the next "input" will be read. But if the input is "inputinput" there is no whitespace to delimit the first "input" so "inputinput" is read into `word`. This does not match "input", it's too long for one thing, so no replacement occurs.

Edit: I think I see part of the confusion. Let's examine the output of "walrus fishfish fish tank" where "fish" is the word to replace and "bird" is the replacement.

```
Iteration 1: walrus != fish. No replacement.   Line = "walrus fishfish fish tank" 
Iteration 2: fishfish != fish. No replacement. Line = "walrus fishfish fish tank" 
Iteration 3: fish == fish. Replace first fish. Line = "walrus birdfish fish tank" 
Iteration 4: tank != fish. No replacement.     Line = "walrus birdfish fish tank"
```

The third "fish" wound up replacing the first "fish" because it was the only acknowledged fish. This gives us a hint as to what we should use instead of `stringstream` and `>>`

End of edit.

Instead of using a `stringstream` and `>>` to parse the line, you are probably better off sticking to `find`

```
auto pos = line.find(target_word);
while (pos != string::npos)
{
    line.replace(pos, target_word.length(), changed_word);
    pos = line.find(target_word);
}
```

or simpler but less obvious:

```
while ((auto pos = line.find(target_word)) != string::npos)
{
    line.replace(pos, target_word.length(), changed_word);
}
```

Note that this will result in an infinite loop if `target_word` is on the line and `target_word == changed_word` because it will always find and replace `target_word` with `target_word`. This case can be checked for early and the program can enter a different path that simply prints the user's input back at them. The user won't be able to tell the difference.